# Good way to scramble html?

Tags: html, scramble

I am embedding my livestream channel on my page so people can see it only there. However, if you look at the source code, you will be able to see the URL of my channel on livestream and see it there which i dont want. I wonder if there is a way to make it human unreadable. I have tried many html scramble pages but they all fail in scrambling the URL.

My embed code is something like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="no" src="//www.livestream.tv/embed/56576778" style="border: 0 none transparent;"></iframe>
```

with the scramblers i have tried so far i get this:

```
<script>var U7=window,W8=document;var a1="%3Ciframe%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22500px%22%20frameborder%3D%22no%22%20src%3D%22//www.livestream.tv/embed/56576778%22%20style%3D%22border%3A%200%20none%20transparent%3B%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E";function V0(){var V0;V0=unescape(a1);W8.write(V0);}V0();</script>
```

Notice how the URL part is still human readable. Not very useful, right? I know that this trick would be useless with computer wizards and savvy users but it will be enough for the average user so im fine with that. No matter whether its a page or a php function i am willing to try.

Thank you.

Comment: You can `encode` the URL somehow but add the decoded URL.

Comment: Thats exactly what i would like to know...

Comment: @Nuker Cristy is talking about encoding, but in the console you will see the url decoded.

Comment: Yeah, in console you would see the `URL` as it is, but I think "average" users do not know how to use the console :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make your URL unreadable because the url will be unusable in SRC attribute. Do you have any programming language installed on your server? Example with PHP:

embedder.php (can be html)

```
<iframe src='iframe.php' width='500' height='500'></iframe>
```

iframe.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) 
    || $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] !== "http://localhost/embedder.php") exit;
header("Location: http://www.livestream.tv/embed/56576778");
?>
```

When you try to direct access the 'iframe.php' then the redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: So iframe.php wont be accessible by typing the url into the address bar?

Comment: I just tried your method. It works great, thank you.